# Number of draws that contain at least $k$ red coins

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Assume there are $n$ coins in an urn from which $r$ are read. What is the number of draws of $r$ coins that contain at least $k$ red coins? It is obvious that there are $$\binom{r}{k}\binom{n-r}{r-k}$$ draws that contain exactly $k$ red coins. From which it is also clear that there are $$\binom{n}{r}-\binom{n-r}{r}$$ draws with at least $1$ red coin. To put it in formulas, I am interested in $$\sum_{j=k}^r\binom{r}{j}\binom{n-r}{r-j}$$ or at least a good lower bound on it.

Comment: [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net)'s implementation of the Gosper-Zeilberger algorithm tells me this isn't Gosper summable, so your only hope is some approximation. What kind of values of $n$, $r$, $k$ are of interest?

Comment: I am only interested in the asymptotics $n\to\infty$. My claim would be that if $r$ grows faster than $\sqrt{n}$ and $k$ grows slower than $r/\sqrt{n}$ then asymptotically all draws of $r$ coins contain at least $r$ red coins. I.e. if $A(n,r,k)$ is the quantity I am interested in, I think/hope that $A(n,r,k)/\binom{n}{r}\approx 1$ for large $n$.